# Calculating factorial in terms of certain powers

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Factorial $n!$ is defined to be$$n!=1·2·3·4\cdots n$$Let's choose base $2$ to represent $n!$, thus$$n!=2^0·2^1·(2^1+2^0)·2^2·(2^2+2^0)·(2^2+2^1)·(2^2+2^1+2^0)\cdots$$Of course, it is just binary representation of each term of multiplication by entire definition of factorial, but still, is there a gerenzalized formula for calculating factorial for certain natural bases? In particular, for base $2$?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculating a factorial for a base"?

Comment: In computer science, among with binary form of the number, there are other bases can be used, for example, decimal number $10$ is $10 = 2^3+2^1$ in terms of base 2 and so on

Comment: So you mean a formula/computation technique for finding the $k$th bit (or trinary bit, etc.) of $n!$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Look to the decimal to binary table https://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-binary-conversion-table/ , each integer in range $2^k$ is combination of zeroes and ones within $k+1$ elements. I believe that it can be expressed in terms of certain multinimial or binomial coefficients

Comment: You can start by counting the number of factors of $2$ in $n!$ because as many least significant bits will be $0$s in the binary representation of $n!$.  Same for all other bases.